# ACCESS another page when clicking on the second menu

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css

I created a menu with jQuery UI Accordion, walking without any problem. here is my problem:
after closing the menu, I want to access it a different page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried attaching a listener to the method or event that closes the menu?

Here are some [JQuery event listeners](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/)

What you could try to do is to add a `bind()` to the event that closes the menu. Once you do that you can just fire a `window.location` call to redirect.

Look [here for information on bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)